# AJAX GET request hits Controller but doesn't go to URL in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm implementing bootstrap typeahead.js and trying to utilize a simple AJAX GET request like so:

```
$("#find-company-search").typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        var companies = [];
        map = {};

        // This is going to make an HTTP post request to the controller
        return $.post('/Companies/GetCompanies', { query: query }, function (data) {

            //console.log(data);

            // Loop through and push to the array
            $.each(data, function (i, company) {
                console.log(company);
                console.log(company.CompanyID);
                // Use the Name field on the display and for the map key.
                map[company.Name] = company;
                companies.push(company.Name);
            });

            // Process the details
            process(companies);
        });
    },
    updater: function (item) {
        console.log(item);
        console.log(map[item]);
        console.log(map[item].CompanyID);

        var selected = map[item].CompanyID;

        // Put ajax code to load the company here.
        $.ajax({
            url: "/companies/?companyID=" + selected,
            success: function() {
                alert("Success!");
            }
        });

        return item;
    }
});
```

When I make the request, it hits the following controller action method:

```
    public ActionResult Index() {
        if (CurrentUser.IsCompany(User)) {
            // We need to cast to a Company list
            return View(new List<Company> { db.Companies.Find(CurrentUser.CompanyID(User)) });
        }

        var filters = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        var companyID = 0;
        Int32.TryParse(Request.Params["companyID"], out companyID);

        filters["companyID"] = companyID;
        filters["hasTickets"] = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Params["has-tickets"] == "on");
        filters["hasDevices"] = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Params["has-devices"] == "on");
        filters["isCustomer"] = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Params["type"] == "customer");
        filters["isVendor"] = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Params["type"] == "vendor");
        filters["isLead"] = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Params["type"] == "lead");

        ViewBag.Filters = filters;

        var companies = db.Companies.Where(c => c.Hidden != true);

        ViewBag.CompaniesForDropdown = companies.ToList();

        if (filters.Count(filter => filter.Value <= 0) == filters.Count()) {
            // Return nothing if we haven't filtered. 
            return View(new List<Company>());
        }

        foreach (var filter in filters.Where(filter => filter.Value > 0)) {
            // <= 0 means false, or no selected company, so ignore those.
            switch (filter.Key) {
                case "companyID":
                    companies = companies.Where(c => c.CompanyID == companyID);
                    break;
                case "hasTickets":
                    companies = companies.Where(c => c.ServiceTickets.Count > 0);
                    break;
                case "hasDevices":
                    companies = companies.Where(c => c.Devices.Count > 0);
                    break;
                case "isCustomer":
                    companies =
                        companies.Where(c => c.Company_CompanyType.Count(t => t.CompanyType.Name == "Customer") > 0);
                    break;
                case "isVendor":
                    companies =
                        companies.Where(c => c.Company_CompanyType.Count(t => t.CompanyType.Name == "Vendor") > 0);
                    break;
                case "isLead":
                    companies = companies.Where(c => c.Company_CompanyType.Count(t => t.CompanyType.Name == "Lead") > 0);
                    break;
            }
        }

        return View(companies.OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList());
    }
```

When I submit the text in the input for my bootstrap typeahead, it hits the controller and populates the `companyID` variable as expected, but the page does nothing. However, if I manually navigate to the URL in my browser (e.g. /companies/?companyID=1604), all of my data is displayed as expected. Is there something wrong with my AJAX request?

EDIT: I should specify the AJAX request that is in question, which is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/companies/?companyID=" + selected,
    success: function() {
        alert("Success!");
    }
});
```

Comment: You only have one callback to your ajax requests, the success callback. If you also provide the fail callback, you might discover something useful.

Comment: @RaphaelSerota I've added an error callback and it never hits it. It does, however, display my success alert.

Comment: In your success callback, the data returned can be referenced as a parameter. Please log this and check to see what you're getting back. Also, as Raphael said, add and log the other handlers as well.

Comment: @Ngz I have logged the data returned and it is returning basically the entirety of my View (HTML and JavaScript).

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the request in the Chrome inspector? Sounds like the webserver isn't returning the JSON, either due to an exception (invalid request, missing request headers, no matching company) or isn't configured properly. What backend are you using?

Comment: @Ngz It won't let me post a screenshot right now, but from Chrome:
Path: ?companyID=1
Method: GET
Status: 200 OK
Type: text/html
Initiator: jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
Size: 3.9KB
Time: 296 ms

Comment: @mdk09 What about the response? Can you get on a Google hangout or something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63717/discussion-between-mdk09-and-ngz).

Answer (score 0):

You need to navigate your page to the specified url:

```
updater: function (item) {
    var selected = map[item].CompanyID;

    window.location.replace("/companies", "/companies/?companyID=" + selected);
}
```

**Edit**: changed answer based on Ngz's suggestion.

Comment: Correct, but not in the success function. The AJAX request in the updater is actually pointless if just doing a redirect based on company ID.

Comment: Well, he really wouldn't need the updater function at all in this case, correct?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the plugin, but 'updater' just means that someone has selected a typeahead option, so in that case he just needs to redirect the window.location to the correct endpoint.
[Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to send request to controller by redirecting page, then HTTP Methods `GET` would completely satisfy your needs.

One of beauties of Ajax is that ***Web applications can send data to and retrieve from a server asynchronously (in the background) without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page.*** (via [Wikipadia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)))

Why would you like to use Ajax call?

In your case, the method in controller returns View that's why when you manually hit the URL, the view will be return as expected.